# TypeScript installed, but not being recognized by VS Code or Windows

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, installation

I've recently been working on a small project in VS Code that is primarily typescript.

I committed it to a GitHub repository and downloaded it onto a machine that I regularly use for TypeScript development.  However, when I try to build my VS Code project, I get the error:

```
tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

After reading other StackOverflow questions on the subject, I tried a few things:

1. Installed typescript using npm, with the command `npm install -g typescript` - I received no error messages, so it seems the install was successful (confirmed in Step 3).
2. Checked my envrionmental variables to ensure I wasn't pointing to any unusual locations for the `tsc` compiler.  I found none.
3. Ran the command `npm list -g` to ensure that TypeScript installed (it did.)
4. As a sanity check, ran the command from the path found in Step 3, resembling `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc` - the path ran
5. With the sanity check's results in mind, opened a clean command prompt, and tried running `tsc -v` - command was not recognized by the OS.
6. Ran the command `setx path "%paths%:C:\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm"` to try to add the npm global directory to the system environment `paths` variable.  Upon running the command, closed the command line, opened a new one, and tried an unqualified `tsc` command.  No luck.

It's almost as if the `npm install -g typescript` command isn't enough to *actually* install TypeScript such that the system recognizes it on a global basis (despite using the -g/"global" flag).  Clearly I'm missing something.  What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating node.js to 10.13.0 LTS, after closing and re-opening both my command prompt and VS Code, `tsc` runs.

So, *be sure you update node if you start getting funny feedback from tsc!*